# Can't get the Leaks instrument to appear when profiling in Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: xcode4.2

I created an iPhone app and am wanting to test it for leaks. When I was using Snow Leapard Xcode 4.2 when I clicked Profile -> Leaks it would start profiling. In Lion Xcode 4.2.1 it gives me a blank Profiler where I have to add the libraries. I am unable to add Leaks. How do I prepare the Profiler to test for leaks? Also why is Xcode 4.2.1 require you to add the libraries when 4.2 already had it all set up for you?

Comment: It sounds like something strange with your installation/configuration of Xcode. I get the expected behavior under 4.2.1/Lion.

Comment: @smparkes so when you click Product -> Profile then select links it auto opens with everything? For me i get a little error noise but no message and an empty profiler asking for me to add libraries

Comment: @jostster: when I select Profile/CMD-I, it opens Instruments and Instruments pops up its template selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I thought this was what Xcode 4.2.1 was supposed to do. After hearing it worked the same as 4.2 for everyone else I did a fresh install of Xcode again and now it seems to open the allocations and leaks profiler automatically without the error sound. I guess something got corrupt during the initial install.